# How can I loop object observer on vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

If I `console.log(this.list)`, the result like this :

[image]

```
this.list.forEach(function (user) {
    selected.push(user.id);
});
```

There exist error :

> Uncaught TypeError: this.list.forEach is not a function

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Try `Array.from(this.list).forEach`?

Comment: are you checking and getting on same block `console.log(this.list)` and `this.list.forEach` ?

Comment: Since its reactive, you might not seeing the initial data. Did you set initial data as empty array?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is `this.list` not an Array?

If `this.list` is array-like (there must be a `length` property on that object), you should be able to do:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.list, user => {
  // ...
})
```

or

```js
Array.from(this.list).forEach(user => {
  // ...
})
```

or

```js
[...this.list].forEach(user => {
  // ...
})
```

Otherwise if `this.list` is just a plain object, you can do:

```js
Object.keys(this.list).forEach(key => {
  const user = this.list[key]
  // ...
})
```

or

```js
Object.entries(this.list).forEach(([key, user]) => {
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to loop over an observer array in Vue:

```
let keys = Object.keys(myObserverArray);

keys.forEach(key => {
   let item = myObserverArray[key];
   //...work with item
})
```