# why doesn't my for each iteration work on my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, foreach

i have not that much expierience with javascript. in my project I want to iterate over an array, unfortunately it doesn't work and I can't find a solution.
in my array are 3 objects see screenshots from console log.
after the iteration I want to output the objects individually using a console log. but this does not work.

here the picture of the console:[image]

here is my code:

```
var url;
console.log("All Configs -> ", this.segmenteConfig);
this.segmenteConfig.forEach(segmenteConfig => {
    console.log("used config -> ", segmenteConfig)
    if (segmenteConfig.type === type) {
       url = segmenteConfig.url;
       console.log("used configs url -> ", url);
    }
})
```

Comment: What is `type`?

Comment: and what contain `this.segmenteConfig` ?

Comment: it looks like you have an object with numeric keys instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

In you case `this.segmenteConfig` is not an array. As shown in the first console statement it is a `[__ob__: Observer]`. First convert it to normal JS object/array.

Refrence: [Vue JS returns [__ob__: Observer] data instead of my array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873516/vue-js-returns-ob-observer-data-instead-of-my-array-of-objects)

Comment: Thanks but it is not working because the array is now empty

Comment: Well in that case you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52873516/vue-js-returns-ob-observer-data-instead-of-my-array-of-objects

Comment: there is no solution for me i think, i tried some of them but they does not work

Comment: If possible, please create a code sandbox.

Comment: i think my project is to big for it

Comment: there are too much scripts, and jsons

Comment: do you have another solution for this problem ?

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md#array-likes

Comment: no it is not solving my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388040/how-can-i-loop-object-observer-on-vue-js-2